# Якори и fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, fullpage

В общем задача такая, у меня есть макет, на котором нужно реализовать плагин fullPage, также там на главной странице имеются несколько якорей, которые работают не корректно, я уже искал ответ на вопрос, старался по другому оформить, но всегда скроллинг по якорям происходит не корректно. Код html прикладываю

```
<ul class="nav_list" id="menu">
  <li class="nav_item"><a  data-menuanchor="header" class="nav_link " href="#header">Главная</a data-anchor="firstSlide"></li>
  <li class="nav_item"><a  data-menuanchor="team" class="nav_link " href="#team">Команды</a></li>
  <li class="nav_item"><a  data-menuanchor="grid" class="nav_link " href="#grid">Сетка</a></li>
  <li class="nav_item"><a class="nav_link" href="#">Правила</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="mouse">
  <a data-anchor="grid" href="#" class="anchor"><img src="img/mouse.svg" alt="" class="svg mouse_icon"></a> 
  <a data-anchor="header" href="#" class="anchor"><span class="mouse__point_1"></span></a>
  <a data-anchor="grid" href="#" class="anchor"><span class="mouse__point_2"></span></a>
  <a data-anchor="team" href="#" class="anchor"><span class="mouse__point_3"></span></a>
</div>
```

Код активации fullpage:

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {anchors: ['header', 'grid', 'team']});
```

Стандартный скроллинг этого плагина работает хорошо, а якори совсем не корректно, могут перебросить на другую секцию. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: fullpage это что?

Comment: плагин, для скроллинга по секциям

Comment: а обычный скрол не работает? нативный плавный скрол существует

Comment: По секциям и нативный?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link

Comment: якори должны корректно работать при двух условиях: 1. наличие href="#elem", 2. наличие элемента с id="elem" (скорее всего одного на странице, все-таки это id :) )

Comment: Я знаю про якори, тут суть не в них

Comment: А в скроллинге по секциям и реализации с якорями https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ru/